# Saving an image of an expression displayed with Sympy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I'm relatively new to Sympy and had a lot of trouble with the information that I was able to scavenge on this site. My main goal is basically to take a string, representing some mathematical expression, and then save an image of that expression but in a cleaner form.

So for example, if this is the expression string:
"2**x+(3-(4*9))"
I want it to display like this
[cleaner image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdXct.png)

This is currently the code that I have written in order to achieve this, based off of what I was able to read on StackExchange:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.printing.preview import preview


class MathString:

    def __init__(self, expression_str: str):
        self.expression_str = expression_str

    @property
    def expression(self):
        return parse_expr(self.expression_str)

    def plot_expression(self):
        return plot(self.expression)

    def save_plot(self):
        self.plot_expression().saveimage("imagePath", 
        format='png')
```

And then using a main function:

```
def main():
    test_expression = '2**x+(3-(4*9))'
    test = MathString(test_expression)
    test.save_plot()


main()
```

However, when I run main(), it just sends me an actual graphical plot of the equation I provided. I've tried multiple other solutions but the errors ranged from my environment not supporting LaTeX to the fact that I am passing trying to pass the expression as a string.

Please help! I'm super stuck and do not understand what I am doing wrong! Given a certain address path where I can store my images, how can I save an image of the displayed expression using Sympy/MatPlotLib/whatever other libraries I may need?

Answer (score 0):

The program in your question does not convert the expression from
string format to the `sympy` internal format. See below for examples.

Also, `sympy` has capabilities to detect what works best in your
environment. Running the following program in Spyder 5.0 with an
iPython 7.22 terminal, I get the output in Unicode format.

```
from sympy import *

my_names = 'x'
x = symbols(','.join(my_names))
ns1 = {'x': x}
my_symbols = tuple(ns1.values())
es1 = '2**x+(3-(4*9))'
e1 = sympify(es1, locals=ns1)
e2 = sympify(es1, locals=ns1, evaluate=False)
print(f"String {es1} with symbols {my_symbols}",
      f"\n\tmakes expression {e1}",
      f"\n\tor expression {e2}")
# print(simplify(e1))
init_printing()
pprint(e2)
```

Output (in Unicode):

```
# String 2**x+(3-(4*9)) with symbols (x,)
#   makes expression 2**x - 33
#   or expression 2**x - 4*9 + 3
#  x
# 2  - 4⋅9 + 3
```

Comment: I understand how to print expressions to unicode using init_printing. I'm just trying to find a way to export the expression as a png in the style found in the linked image.